# How do I translate the `docker network create` CLI options into compose format for `docker stack deploy` use?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

**Use-case context:** I need to do some batch processesing via `docker run` that connects to services using the swarm overlay network.
I want to use `docker stack deploy` to roll out the networking and service setups;
the individual container task spooling is done directly through the REST API.

Thus, I'd like to express the following shell command in terms of a `docker-compose.yml` version 3+ file.

```
$ docker network create \
    --driver overlay \
    --opt encrypted \
    --internal \
    --attachable \
    --subnet 10.42.6.0/24 \
    example_net
```

Inspecting this network gives good detail of how the arguments are interpreted.

```
$ docker network inspect example_net

[{
  "Name": "example_net",
  "Id": "lw689m2su19p5imljtlfsfsxy",
  "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "Scope": "swarm",
  "Driver": "overlay",
  "EnableIPv6": false,
  "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Options": null,
      "Config": [
          {
              "Subnet": "10.42.6.0/24",
              "Gateway": "10.42.6.1"
          }
      ]
  },
  "Internal": true,
  "Attachable": true,
  "Containers": null,
  "Options": {
      "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4098",
      "encrypted": ""
  },
  "Labels": null
}]
```

Translating those inspection results into my first cut at the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.1"
networks:
  example_net:
    internal: true
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: ""
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.4.0/24

services:
  db:
    image: couchdb
    networks:
      - example_net
    hostname: "{{.Service.Name}}-{{.Task.Slot}}-{{.Node.ID}}"
```

…arriving at a close configuration result:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c ./docker-compose.yml test

Creating network test_example_net
Creating service test_db

$ docker network inspect example_net

[{
  "Name": "test_example_net",
  "Id": "j1ahedyfh05mpg5g52vrd9034",
  "Created": "2017-04-21T21:00:55.656972306Z",
  "Scope": "swarm",
  "Driver": "overlay",
  "EnableIPv6": false,
  "IPAM": {
      "Driver": "default",
      "Options": null,
      "Config": [
          {
              "Subnet": "172.16.4.0/24",
              "Gateway": "172.16.4.1"
          }
      ]
  },
  "Internal": true,
  "Attachable": false,
  "Containers": { ...  },
  "Options": {
      "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4100",
      "encrypted": ""
  },
  "Labels": {"com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"},
  "Peers": [ ... ]
}]
```

**Question**: Is there a way to set `"Attachable": true` with the `docker stack deploy` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a github issue for ["attachable property not supported in docker-compose v3 format"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30191).

> This was added in [#30742](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/30742). It will be in Compose file v3.2 format in the next release.

So that should be in the 1.12 release of Compose and probably needs a 17+ release of Docker for `docker stack`